# C# Не видит текстовый файл в папке

Tags: c#, файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Не находит текстовый документ **
[image: введите сюда оп исание изображения]

Comment: у вас скрыто отображение расширений файлов, т.к не видно exe или config, поэтому возможно файл называется map1.txt.txt

Comment: +1, включите расширения файлов. Можете также открыть cmd и сделать `dir` в этой папке, чтобы увидеть настоящие названия файлов

Comment: Код и текст ошибки нужно вставлять текстом, а не картинками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас отключены разрешения у файлов, так как у .exe файлов так же отсутствует расширение.

Иными словами map1.txt у вас называется map1.txt.txt

Первым делом включите отображение расширений файлов:

- В меню **Пуск** в поиске напишите "папок" и найдите [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Откройте вкладу `вид`, и отключите галочку "скрывать расширение для зарегистрированных типов файлов":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И вместо ручного добавления файлов в ваш проект добавляйте их через Visual Studio**:

- Перекиньте файл (можно мышкой) в обозреватель решений: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Выделите файл и укажите `Действие при сборке` на `Внедрённый ресурс` и `Копировать в выходной каталог` на `Всегда копировать`:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]